# Get max value from each point in matrix

Tags: r, matrix, max

I have 2 data frames

```
a = c(1,1,3)
b = c(7,2,1)
c = c(2,4,2)

d1 = cbind(a,b,c)

d = c(2,1,6)
e = c(1,4,2)
f = c(4,8,4)

d2 = cbind(d,e,f)
```

How can i easily get data frame of max value in each point

```
_fun(d1,d2)

     a b c
[1,] 2 7 4
[2,] 1 4 8
[3,] 6 2 4
```

I can do it using loop but its very slow for big dataframe.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can keep the datasets in a `list` and use `do.call` with `f` as `pmax`.

```
do.call(pmax, list(d1, d2))
#     a b c
#[1,] 2 7 4
#[2,] 1 4 8
#[3,] 6 2 4
```

Or use `pmax` directly

```
pmax(d1, d2)
```

EDIT: Based on @nicola's comments.

It might be faster to use `pmax.int`, but converting back to `matrix` might be slower.

```
matrix(pmax.int(d1, d2), dim(d1))
```

#### Benchmarks

```
set.seed(24)
m1 <- matrix(sample(0:9, 5000*5000, replace=TRUE), ncol=5000)
set.seed(48)
m2 <- matrix(sample(0:9, 5000*5000, replace=TRUE), ncol=5000)
akrun1 <- function() pmax(m1, m2)
akrun2 <- function() matrix(pmax.int(m1, m2), dim(m1))
colonel <- function() ifelse(m1 > m2, m1, m2)
system.time(akrun1())
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.850   0.033   0.885 
system.time(akrun2())
#   user  system elapsed 
#  1.090   0.021   1.114 

system.time(colonel())
#   user  system elapsed 
#  5.049   0.336   5.395
```

Comment: No need of any `Reduce`. Just `pmax(d1,d2)` works. Furthermore, if the elements to compare are more than two, you should use `do.call` and not `Reduce` (which is slower). `do.call(pmax, list(d1, d2))` is much better.

Comment: @nicola Thanks, I was in the process of changing to `pmax(d1, d2)` when you commented.

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel  It looks fast, but I am not sure whether creating an additional object would be memory efficient for big datasets

Answer (score 4):

Or simply use `ifelse` which is vectorized:

```
ifelse(d1>d2, d1, d2)
#     a b c
#[1,] 2 7 4
#[2,] 1 4 8
#[3,] 6 2 4
```

Or a self built function (just to test speed):

```
func = function(d1, d2) {m=d2;m[d1>d2]=d1[d1>d2];m}
```

And some benchmarks, finally the self built function seems to be the fastest (but @Akrun's solution is fast enough and should be fine as well for your problem):

```
#> d2 = matrix(sample(9000000), ncol=3000)
#> d1 = matrix(sample(9000000), ncol=3000)
#> system.time(ifelse(d1>d2, d1, d2))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   2.13    0.37    2.49 
#> system.time(matrix(pmax.int(d1, d2), dim(d1)))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.44    0.00    0.43 
#> system.time(pmax(d1, d2))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.41    0.02    0.42 
#> system.time(do.call(pmax, list(d1, d2)))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.34    0.01    0.36 
#> system.time(func(d1,d2))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.32    0.03    0.36
```

Comment: As fact i need to get max using more than 2 df , but Thank for help

Answer (score 1):

you can also use the `abind` to create an array and then just use `apply` like so:

```
library(abind)

d3 <- abind(d1, d2, along = 3)
apply(d3, c(1, 2), max)
```

Comment: I tried this method using the  big dataset in my post.  It seems to be very slow i.e. 306 for system.time

Comment: yes, with a very large dataset i would expect this approach to be subpar